# How do I change the value of [n] with a button using a [n] value?

Tags: python, tkinter

Okay, I'm doing a project for school which is to make a Connect 4, the whole point is to use the buttons at the top to set the colour of the labels the colour depending on the turn. I'm stumped, I can't set the colour of the ones at the bottom unless I set the n value to [n+35]. Here is my code so far. Also, I still do not have the win conditions in place, I'll do that later. Right now all I'm looking for is help on how to set the labels to light up properly.

Thank you in advance for any help.
(Sorry for being a coding noob so far.)

```
from Tkinter import *
from functools import partial

top = Tk()

top.title("Juan's Zany Super Crazy Connect Four!")

turn=1

def click(n):
    global turn
    if turn==1:
        board[35+n].config(state=DISABLED, bg='blue')
        turn=turn+1
    elif turn==2:
        board[35+n].config(state=DISABLED, bg='red')
        turn=turn-1

top = Tk()
r=0
count=0
col=0

buttonList = list()
for i in range(7):
    buttonList.append(Button(text=str(i), font='Helvetica 48', command=partial(click, i)))
    buttonList[-1].grid(row=r,column=col, sticky='NESW')
    count+=1
    col+=1

r=1
col=0
count=0

board = list()

for i in range(42):
    board.append(Label(text=(i), font='Helvetica 15', bg='grey80'))
    board[-1].grid(row=r,column=col, sticky='NESW', padx=2, pady=2)
    count+=1
    col+=1
    if count==7:
        r=r+1
        count=0
        col=0


top.mainloop()
```

Update (4/5/2016):

```
from Tkinter import *
from functools import partial
import time

#time.sleep()

top = Tk()

top.title("Juan's Zany Super Crazy Connect Four!")

turn=1

nextS=[35,36,37,38,39,40,41]

def buttonStuff(z):
    global turn
    if turn==1:
        board[nextS[z]].config(bg='blue')
        nextS[z]=nextS[z]-7
        turn=turn+1
        if nextS[z]<0:
            buttonList[z].config(state=DISABLED)

    elif turn==2:
        board[nextS[z]].config(bg='red')
        nextS[z]=nextS[z]-7
        turn=turn-1
        if nextS[z]<0:
            buttonList[z].config(state=DISABLED)

def checkWin():
    for h in range (0,4):
        if board[35+h].cget('bg')==board[36+h].cget('bg')==board[37+h].cget('bg')==board[38+h].cget('bg')!=bg=='yellow':
            for q in range (0,4):
                board[35+h].config(bg='green')
                board[36+h].config(bg='green')
                board[37+h].config(bg='green')
                board[38+h].config(bg='green')
                time.sleep(0.5)
                if turn==1:
                    board[35+h].config(bg='blue')
                    board[36+h].config(bg='blue')
                    board[37+h].config(bg='blue')
                    board[38+h].config(bg='blue')
                if turn==2:
                    board[35+h].config(bg='red')
                    board[36+h].config(bg='red')
                    board[37+h].config(bg='red')
                    board[38+h].config(bg='red')



top = Tk()
r=0
count=0
col=0

buttonList = list()
for z in range(7):
    buttonList.append(Button(text=str(z), font='times 48', command=partial(buttonStuff, z)))
    buttonList[-1].grid(row=r,column=col, sticky='NESW')
    count+=1
    col+=1

r=1
col=0
count=0

board = list()
for z in range(42):
        board.append(Label(text='', font='Helvetica 15', bg='grey80'))
        board[-1].grid(row=r,column=col, sticky='NESW', padx=2, pady=2, ipadx=2, ipady=25)
        count+=1
        col+=1
        if count==7:
            r=r+1
            count=0
            col=0


top.mainloop()
```

What I want to accomplish is to get just one row working right now (the bottom row), I want it to flash blue/red depending on the turn/the player who 'captured' those 4 in a row. Just struggling a bit with it, so if one of you guys could take a quick look. Also please keep it basic like this since I want to learn what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should use the canvas widget instead of using labels

Comment: You haven't said what it is supposed to do so there is little we can do to help.  The game only sets the bottom row now.  How does it know which row to use?  Also setting state=DISABLED for a label does not change a label AFAIK. Note that the top row is [0+n] the next row is [7+n] the next row is [14+n] and the bottom row is [35+n]. i.e. the first 7 in board is the first row, the second 7 is the second row, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `click` function like so:

```
def click(n):
    global turn
    offset = 0
    while board[35 + n - offset]['bg'] in {'blue', 'red'}:
        offset += 7
    if turn==1:
        board[35+n-offset].config(state=DISABLED, bg='blue')
        turn=turn+1
    elif turn==2:
        board[35+n-offset].config(state=DISABLED, bg='red')
        turn=turn-1
```

If you need more help, feel free to ask!

Comment: Okay! Thank you very much. Very helpful. This definitely helped guide me on the right path, now what I need to work on is the checkWin def. I understand how to do it but I'm having a small problem with getting it to work, I was wondering if you could take a quick look at it.

Comment: @JuanJaramillo Try posting a separate question instead. This is not like a regular forum where conversations are supposed to take place. Instead, each "thread" is a place for one question and multiple answers. As people vote on what the best answer is, the one who posted the question can select an answer to accept out of all given answers. Further questions need to be asked separately. You may provide a link to this question, though, for reference purposes (both for yourself and others).